# Getting error no matter what Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I know there are like a billion questions on this site, but none of the solutions helped me out

getting Uncaught TypeError:

> Cannot set property 'value' of null with my chrome extension after pressing the button in my popup

This is just meant to fill the fieldAccount and fieldPassword with values.

**My popup.js:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var login = document.getElementById('record');
  login.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var user = 'a';
    var pass = 'a';
    var loginField = document.getElementById('fieldAccount');
    var passwordField = document.getElementById('fieldPassword');
    loginField.value = user;
    passwordField.value = pass;
  });
});
```

I know that the fields "fieldAccount" and "fieldPassword" exist and I have the DOMContentLoaded listener. Proof: [fieldAccount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgSKy.png) [fieldPassword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWv84.png)

Comment: You might now that you have  "fieldAccount" and "fieldPassword", but the error you get tells you that either the loginField or passwordField is null, and the field wan't found. Can you `console.log("login",loginField, "password", passwordField)`. (Maybe you have misspelled the name of one of the fields)

Comment: Show the html for the fields "fieldAccount" and "fieldPassword" .

Comment: Yeah so it returns null for both loginField and passwordField

Comment: *I know that the fields "fieldAccount" and "fieldPassword" exist*. Where do they exist ? Are they part of your extension's pop-up window or part of a webpage ?

Comment: No the website I'm trying to fill the fields on. I'll attach a ss

Comment: The pop-up's context is different then a tab's context, you cannot access a website's DOM from a pop-up directly. You should take a look at [activeTab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) and [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)

Comment: Should I just have the popup.js execute a script to access the website's DOM?

Comment: Yes, you can call `chrome.tabs.executeScript` on the active tab and use the code in the click listener, eg: `chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: 'var user = "a"; var pass = "a" ....'})`.

Comment: That gives me a new error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'

Comment: The value of `code` has to be a string, `{code: ".."}`.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help, good luck.